# How to "float: top" or close vertical gap between divs of equal size

Tags: html, css

What I got is this:

```
 ______________________________
|              | |             |
| div 1        | | div 2       |
|              | |             |
|______________| |             |
|                |             |
| wrapper        |_____________|
|______________   _____________|
|              | |  div 4      |
| div 3        | |_____________|
|______________|_______________|
```

Now, what I want is this:

```
 ______________________________
|              | |             |
| div 1        | | div 2       |
|              | |             |
|______________| |             |
|______________  |             |
|              | |_____________|
| div 3        |  _____________|
|______________| |  div 4      |
|   wrapper      |_____________|
|______________________________|
```

Is there maybe a way to do this via css(3) only?

Comment: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `float: top`, but you can float divs 1 and 3 left, and 2 and 4 right. Then they will float into the space above them.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsx0hjy5/)

```
<div class="left">1</div>
<div class="right">2</div>
<div class="left">3</div>
<div class="right">4</div>
```